# How to find 3d Projection Matrix in Surf Detection

Tags: opencv, 3d, homography

I am new to OpenCV. I have got the Surf Detection sample working. Now I want to place a 3d model on the detected image.

How can I find the 3d Projection matrix?

Comment: Possible solution : http://urbanar.blogspot.in/2011/04/from-homography-to-opengl-modelview.html

Comment: The problem is too complex for that simple question. You mean the Homography. You have to pass the keypoints detected with surf to the function cvFindHomography

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are talking about Augment Reality as you say you want to place a 3D model on the detected image (in the camera frame? ). They key of the problem is always to detect at least 4 points that match other 4 "keypoints" in our marker. Then, solving some equations we will  get our homography, which will allow us to project any point.

In OpenCV there is a function that performs this task: [cvFindHomography](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography)

You just need the pairs of matches, select a method (RANSAC, i.e.) and you will get the Homography.

Then you can project the points like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10750648/744859):

Comment: I used cvFindHomography to project a test square on to the image and then called solvePnP to compute the modelview matrix.