# Getting x,y in 3d coordinate system from 2d image pixel

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, pose-estimation

Using camera with fixed position I have to track an object in motion and to localize it in some pre chosen coordinate system. Idea is to put a specific color marker on the top of the object with known height, so the Z coordinate will be known. After color tracking is done, I need to find out the X and Y from u and v image coordinates where the color is found. I have already done camera calibration and I'm planning to use cv::solvePnP to get rotation and translation vector. Also, I have learned about color tracking [here](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/) and wrote a C++ api from it.

I have already found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7836134) and learned a lot from it, but the difference is that I only need to evaluate X and Y, since the Z coordinate is known (measured before). How can I get those X and Y coordinates with pre specified Z? Thanks for help!

Comment: This question probably only makes sense to you. You need to show what you're tried and what your specific issue is.

Comment: I would like to do as Jav_Rock described in his answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10750648), just, as I described in my question, I already have my Z coordinate (it's the height where color marker is). So, I would like to hard-code my Z coordinate and to get only X and Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have calibrated (i presume on z=0) you can go from pixel to rw coordinates using the camera, translation and rotation matrices.

1. You find a point you want to know the rw coordinates of. (the color marker)
2. You lookup the x and y coordinate of this point (assuming z=0)
3. You calculate the angles in x and y (in relation to the principle point)
4. You use these angles to calculate what x and y would be at z=objectHeight

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514357/converting-a-2d-image-point-to-a-3d-world-point/14602271#14602271) to project an image point onto the z=0 plane.

Answer (score 0):

After you calibrated and obtained extrinsic and intrinsic parameters, you can use the informations about

- u,v coordinates
- z coordinate

to find X e Y in world coordinates:

- Pc = R * Pw + T

Where Pc cam coordinate, Pw world coordinate, R rotation matrix and T translation vector.

Comment: This goes from known world coordinates to image coordinates. The questions is about the inverse.